# Passing data from child to parent , but unable to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So, i am trying to pass data from child component to parent component. I was able to do this through using props and is able to print the data using console.log. However, when i try to setState in the parent component using this data from child component. I am stuck in infinite loop of updating state which caused error "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

My code is of below

Parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TagsPaper from './tagsPaper'
import CurrentTagPaper from './currentTagPaper'
import ApiCall from './Backend/apiCall';

export default class Tags extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tags: ["apple"],
            toUpdate: true,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }
    getTags = (e) => {

        const array = e;
        console.log(array)
        this.setTags(array)
        return array
    }
    setTags(e) {
        this.setState({
            tags: e
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div >
                <p>
                    Get recommendations for articles that matches your
                    interests when you follow more tags:
                </p>
                <b>
                    You are following
                </b>

                <TagsPaper></TagsPaper>
                <b>
                    From this article
                </b>
                {/* pass Tag array name here*/}
                <CurrentTagPaper tagArray={this.state.tags} />
                <ApiCall getTags={this.getTags} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

export default class ApiCall extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      response: '',
      post: '',
      responseToPost: '',
      tags: this.props.tags
    };
    this.sendTags = this.sendTags.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.getTagApi()
  }

  getTagApi(){
    this.callApi()
    .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.express }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/scrap');
    const body = await response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
    return body;
  };
  sendTags = (value) => {
    this.props.getTags(value);
  }

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/forms', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
    });
    const body = await response.text();

    this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
  };

  render() {
    let tagArray = [...this.state.response];
    this.sendTags(tagArray);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* {tagArray.map(e => <p key={e}>{e}</p>)} */}

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p>
            <strong>Post to Server:</strong>
          </p>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ post: e.target.value })}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p>{this.state.responseToPost}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem here is that you are using `this.sendTags(tagArray);` inside `render()`, instead you should use it on `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the parent changes state, it renders the child. When the child renders, it updates the parent state. There would be a few clever ways to fix this, but your ultimate problem is that copying data into both a parent and child's state isn't very idiomatic.

Generally, you should "hoist" any state used by both parent and child to only exist in the parent, and this "hoisting" should happen right off the API call.

In `ApiCall`, you could switch to

```js
  getTagApi(){
    this.callApi()
    .then(res => this.sendTags(res.express))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

In your parent `Tags` component, you would need to pass the parents tag state back down.

```js
<ApiCall getTags={this.getTags} tags={this.state.tags} />
```

Your `ApiTags` would then just use the parent's tags.

```js
    let tagArray = this.props.tags;
```

You also *would not* want to copy `this.props.tags` into `this.state` during construction.

React expects that there be one source-of-truth for all data. If a higher-level component needs the data as well as a lower-level component, you should always hoist the data, as in, pass it up whenever it changes, and pass it back down as a prop on every render.